# How to dismiss notification from Play Store?

Tags: android, kotlin, push-notification

I need to dismiss all notifications from playstore programmatically. I have found the way with the help of the NotificationManager but it ask for ID. So where I can get id's of the system notifications?

Comment: You can't modify what other apps are doing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 even if I am using my own launcher?

Comment: Notifications aren't part of the launcher app.

Comment: @Tenfour04 but is there a way to dismiss it from the status top bar somehow?

Comment: An app being able to dismiss (or otherwise interact with) another app's notifications would be a security issue. Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Get other apps notifications would be a way to steal user's informations, and because of that, this is forbidden at the framework.

If you want all notifications from your app, check [NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications())

Comment: even if I am using my own launcher?